# Specialized template for function signature

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, function-signature

In that test code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class Signal;

template <typename T, typename U>
class Signal<T (U)>
{
public:
  Signal<T (U)>(T (*ptr)(U))
  {
  }
};

void Print(string const& str)
{
  cout << str << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Signal<void (string const&)> sig = &Print;
  return 0;
}
```

Why do I have to write `template <typename T> class Signal;`?

Why do I have to specify it ?

Comment: Because you have to have a primary template in order to be able to specialize one. In this case the primary template is not implemented.

Comment: You don't have to. You can make the primary template parametrized by `T` and `U` if you prefer. That's just not as flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a specialization of `Signal` that combines the arbitrary types `T` and `U` into the form `T(U)`. This is put together as the specialization `Signal<T(U)>`: only one type is in the parameter, which why we forward-declared the `Signal` taking only one type `T`. This wouldn't be possible without that declaration.

Here's a simple example:

```
template <typename T> struct A;

template <typename T, typename U> struct A<T(U)> {

};

int main() {

    A<void(int)> a;

}
```

The types `void` and `int` are bound to the types `T` and `U` respectively. This is combined into the type `void(int)` used in the primary declaration of `A` to specialize the class.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* to do what you're doing, but it's the most flexible approach. A one-parameter template with specialization goes like this:

- A template parametrized on one type...

  ```
  template <typename> struct Foo;
  ```
- ... but it is only defined for function types:

  ```
  template <typename R>
  struct Foo<R()> { /* ... */ };

  template <typename R, typename A1>
  struct Foo<R(A1)> { /* ... */ };

  template <typename R, typename ...Args>
  struct Foo<R(Args...)> { /* ... */ };
  ```

The alternative would be to hard-code the signature of the function:

- A class template that stores the function pointer of a one-argument function:

  ```
  template <typename R, typename A>
  struct Bar
  {
      R (*fp)(A);
      Bar(R(*f)(A)) : fp(f) { }
      // ...
  };
  ```

As you can see, the first approach is much more general, as we can specialize `Foo` for *any* function type we like. By contrast, the direct template in the second example is intricately tied to the details of the function signature and cannot easily be generalized.